# Tailwind CSS: Picture stand out from the top of the div

Tags: html, css, image, tailwind-css

I don't know how to make the picture stand out from the top of the div. Does anyone know how to do this?

[What it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POQEO.png)

[How it should look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPN7y.png)

```
  <div class="px-5 sm:px-10 mx-auto mt-12 mb-10">
      <div class="grid justify-around px-4 py-20 bg-[#1BB3D8] gap-14 lg:gap-16 lg:grid-cols-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 rounded-3xl">
          <img src="/img/landing/WerSindWir.svg" class="w-full">
          <div class="font- text-white my-auto">
              <h3 class="text-break">
                  <span class="text-xl font-[600] tracking-normal">LoremIpsum - LoremIpsum</span><br>
                  <span class="text-30 md:text-5xl"><span class="font-[700]">Wer</span> sind wir?</span>
              </h3>
              <p class="mt-5 text-xl">LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: try giving the image `position: absolute` and try adjusting the placement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `div` with a class `relative` and put the blue `div` and image in it with an `absolute` class. Then you can position the image and blue div separately, relative to the parent with the top, left, right and bottom classes.

In the blue div, set the left margin to the space needed for the image (`ml-72` in the example).

Like:

```
<div class="relative m-12">
  <div id=“BLUEDIV” class="absolute top-24 rounded-3xl bg-[#1BB3D8] px-4 py-20 sm:px-6 lg:grid-cols-2 lg:gap-16 lg:px-8">
    <div class="my-auto text-white ml-72">
      <h3 class="text-break">
        <span class="text-xl font-[600] tracking-normal">LoremIpsum - LoremIpsum</span><br />
        <span class="text-30 md:text-5xl"><span class="font-[700]">Wer</span> sind wir?</span>
      </h3>
      <p class="mt-5 text-xl w-full">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum esse, excepturi alias ut delectus eius.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img id=“IMAGE” class="absolute w-48 h-96 left-12 top-0 rounded-xl" src="https://placekitten.com/100/200"  />
</div>
```

You can see this far from perfect example [working in tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/y60hEgcjBU).